# How to subscribe to GCP Pub/Sub messages within R?

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe

I am working with the Google Cloud Pub/Sub library in Python, https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub

Here it is very easy to subscribe to messages in Pub/Sub:

```
import os
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

topic_name = 'projects/{project_id}/topics/{topic}'.format(
    project_id=os.getenv('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT'),
    topic='MY_TOPIC_NAME',  # Set this to something appropriate.
)

subscription_name = 'projects/{project_id}/subscriptions/{sub}'.format(
    project_id=os.getenv('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT'),
    sub='MY_SUBSCRIPTION_NAME',  # Set this to something appropriate.
)

def callback(message):
    print(message.data)
    message.ack()

with pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient() as subscriber:
    subscriber.create_subscription(
        name=subscription_name, topic=topic_name)
    future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_name, callback)
```

Is there a similar library within R? It seems this functionality is spread across multiple R libraries, mostly written by Mark Edmondson. There is the function `cr_plumber_pubsub()` from [googleCloudRunner](https://code.markedmondson.me/googleCloudRunner/reference/cr_plumber_pubsub.html) but this is to be used within CloudRun. I would like to integrate this R code elsewhere.

What options are available for this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this question was opened more than a few months ago, I guess OP has probably solved his problem by now.

For future readers, I wanted to mention the fact that [`googlePubsubR`](https://github.com/andodet/googlePubsubR) is now available on CRAN and covers the majority of Pub/Sub use caes.